# Webservices Help

Tags: .net, web-services

I have to consume webservice. I have list of methods. How do I use them? I am consuming methods written by some one.

I have added the service using add web refernce. I can create refernce variable of the webservice class and able to see all the methods and properties.

While trying to use them in the application, No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:xxxx.

I think the service is not running..

Do I need to do anything else on the server to keep it running.

I can browse service in IIS and can see WSDL. But I am not sure wheather the service is running or not?

I am struck on this from two days?

Do I use SVc.util to keep the server up and running? I do not know anything about svc.util..

I do not have .asmx file. They just provided me with svc.util, which contains wsdl file...

Do I need to use SVC util to get it sorted..

Many Thanks
Hari Gillala

Comment: What platform? What language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, simply add a web reference, pointing to the wsdl URL.

This will generate a proxy class for you and you will be able to call the methods directly (simply ensure you add the namespace in a `using` directive).

Here are some MSDN links:

- [How to add a web reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx)
- [How to call a web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9.aspx)

Comment: Do I need to use svc.util? or just add web reference?

Comment: @Hari Gillala - Just add it. It calls the utility under the hood.